IGBT gate voltage spike during turn-off
I'm getting a big voltage spike on the gate of an IGBT I'm using to switch high-current and high-voltage as shown in the images, and I wanted to ask what you all think might be causing it. I was thinking it was caused by turn-off being too fast, so I tried increasing the turn-off resistance of the gate-driver which didn't seem to help. The turn-on resistance should be 0.9 Ω which seems fine, the turn-off resistance should be 1.8 Ω which I tried initially, I also tried 0.9, and 4ohm with no change to the spikes on the gate. I'm concerned these will fry the gate of my IGBT since they're up to 100 V, when I'm driving the gate with +15 V, -5 V.
Note; IGBTs are Eupec FZ1200R33KF2C https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_FZ1200R33KF2C_DS_v02_01_EN-3163166.pdf
Gate-Driver is Power-Integrations 2SC0535T2G0-33
https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/documents/2SC0535T2G0-33.pdf
I really appreciate any help/advice you all have to offer me!

Ch1 (Yellow trace) = Gate Signal (measured at IGBT, after gate resistors)
Ch2 (Light-Blue) trace = Voltage across the two parallel IGBTs
Ch3 (Magenta trace) = Current Clamp measured coming off IGBT.
Ch4 (Dark Blue trace) = Rogowski Coil I'm calibrating since other clamp can only do 2 kA

This is my setup of two parallel IGBTs with red snubber capacitors, dual-channel gate-driver to the left of the IGBTs, both current probes, and giant flyback-diode to the right(across the coil I'm switching a capacitor through).
Here's a basic schematic of the system, it's a bit janky, and I'll update once I create a better schematic!

Here's another zoomed in view of scope traces showing the gate voltage spike circled, and the measured peak-to-peak voltage circled

Well, I just put in shielded/coax wire from the gate-driver to the gate and that seemed to solve my gate spike issue atleast for now! I pushed it beyond where the spike would begin appearing and have seen nothing yet. Now I need to work on a reliable way to measure high current (around 50kA) pulses, as my current probe I'm using now can only go to 2kA.


Can you include a schematic of the relevant circuit? It would help us greatly in helping you. You're making us work extra hard by reading your description and just trying to imagine how is your circuit arranged, what could be there and what could not be there.

Your gate probes and wires could simply be picking up the EMP from the main current, try using shorter wires there AND angle them at 90 degrees relative to the main current path, then see if the spikes appear smaller. If your spikes were REALLY that high, the IGBT gates would have already been smoked.

Thank you all for the advice! I've posted a quick&dirty schematic of the system (note; buss-bars connecting both IGBTs in parallel don't show up well, and there are 5x 1uF snubbers. I'll update it with a better schematic hopefully soon!

I ordered some decently beefy shielded cable to connect gate-driver to IGBTs as that would help with noise picked up in those cables. Though not sure if there's a better way to run gate wires from driver to gate, let me know if you all have suggestions there!
Burglups; Are you saying that ~100V spike on the gate is alright? I've added another scope screenshot zoomed in on the spike I'm concerned about. Yes it's a bit janky... I currently have the f.b. diodes directly across the coil, not the IGBT; Is this the right way to do it?

No quick and dirty schematic please. Let's have accurate and clean. Add data sheet links to major components. Add into the question and not comments.

Andy aka; My apologies for my schematic. Do you have any suggestions for what tools I should use to create a schematic/system diagram for this? I've been trying to use Digikey's Scheme-It tool, but it might not be the best, and I can't get their export function to work, hence stitching screenshots together....

Please add pin labels to the IGBT modules on the schematic.

That spike is the result of the capacitive feedthrough the collector to gate capacitance \$C_\text{res}\simeq 8\text{nF}\$ (!!). When the driver turns OFF the IGBT, its collector voltage rises and it injects into the gate a current \$i_\text{CG}\$. Its approximate value is
$$
i_\text{CG} = C_\text{res} \frac{\operatorname{d\!}V_\text{CE}}{\operatorname{d\!} t} \simeq C_\text{res} \frac{\operatorname{d\!}V_\text{CG}}{\operatorname{d\!} t}
$$
since \$V_\text{CE}\$ and \$V_\text{CG}\$ differ for a nearly constant, relatively low value, \$V_\text{GE}\$. In this respect, rising the gate turn-OFF resistance (call it \$ R_{\text{G}_\text{OFF}}\$) only worsen the effect since this feedthrough current must necessarily pass (by the Kirchoff Current Law) and the higher value of the resistance reduces only a few the switching time and thus the slew rate of the collector emitter voltage (i.e. \$\frac{\operatorname{d\!}V_\text{CE}}{\operatorname{d\!} t}\$).
This is an unavoidable effect: it is also present on the gates of power MOSFETs in switching power supplies. Two possible ways of mitigating this effect are shown below in order of effectiveness

Snubbing the collector circuit: design a snubber circuit in order to strongly limit \$\frac{\operatorname{d\!}V_\text{CE}}{\operatorname{d\!}t}\$ at \$t=\text{T}_\text{OFF}\$. This choice is usually also effective in order to reduce EMC problems.
Clamping the gate voltage. This solution is more tricky as if you use a zener clamp, you should choose a device with sufficient power dissipation capability, while if you use an active clamp, this has to be carefully designed in order to avoid power loss increase at turn ON.

Edit: few remarks on the second point above stemming from Hearth's comment. The crude Zener clamp I have in mind can be schematized as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
There are two main problems for this circuit: the first one is that you have to choose a power Zener diode, and "power" in this case possibly means "greater than 5W". The second one maybe even more vicious: you have to find a Zener diode whose differential resistance \$r_Z\$ is lower than the gate turn-OFF resistance \$R_\text{g1}\$.
The active clamping circuit, in my opinion, could possibly be a variation of the standard one known for decades, i.e. the following one

simulate this circuit
However, even this choice requires some effort in order to produce the sought for result: \$Q_1\$ should be a power yet fast \$pnp\$ BJT, and moreover the layout could become critical in this situation.
Finally, I should point that there are also other ways to make an active clamp circuit. For example, the following picture is taken from the Application Note LPD-18 as found in the 1989 Siliconix Low Power Discretes Data Book: it is evidently not possible to use it directly in the application above, but what can we do if instead of a \$n\$-channel depletion MOSFET we use a \$p\$-channel low power JFET driving directly the base of a \$npn\$ medium power BJT?

Edit 2: a look to the Power-Integrations 2SC0535T2G0-33 user manual. After seeing the relevant comment of Drew, had a look at the linked drive manual: at figure 7 at page 11 a recommended gate drive schematics is shown. After a quick look at it is possible to infer that

there is indeed an active clamp pin (ACL1 and ACL2, respectively pins 25 and 18 of the driver), and that
testing such a device with only the two gate resistor possibly does not show the real performance of the circuit.


Most gate drivers designed to drive power IGBTs have Miller clamp pins that do option 2 for you. I'm not convinced a zener clamp is even possible; you wouldn't be able to turn the device on normally if the clamp was always connected.

Hi @Hearth, and thank you very much for your observations. I know that that IGBT gate drivers usually have a Miller clamp but the Asker here seems to put resistor (for rise time, but I suspect EMC, control) just between the output of the driver and the gate terminal (see lab layout picture), thus vanishing the effect of their presence (at least from the point of view of gate protection). For the Zener clamp, perhaps it is not the best idea in such context: I'll add some further notes to the answer.

The miller clamp usually uses a second pin connected directly to the gate.

Thank you all for the input! I'll dig into the gate driver I'm using to see if it supports miller clamping now.

Thanks @Drew: I've added to the answer some relevant comments

Hi all, so to respond to the miller clamping capability of the power-integrations gate driver; I posted on their forum asking whether ACLx was intended for this, and they said it's not; https://www.powerint.cn/zh-hans/community/forum/gate-drivers-forum/2024/2sc0535t2g0-33-acl-active-clamping-same-miller-clamping
